Kendo Combobox Dropdown button is Visible after applying CSP
In my application I am using Kendo Combobox. But after applying <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';"/> in web .config, the combobox dropdown button got disappeared. Can anyone please help me to understand, what happened here? Any inline css got blocked? If it is blocked then how to enable it.
Thanks in Advance...
